# Selenium Webdriver Java code to display message if text on page cannot be found after a set time period

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to write a Java Webdriver method that will log a message if it successfully finds some text on screen. If it doesn't find it within a given time period I would also like to log an appropriate message. The code below works to search for the text. Please could some one give me an example of how I can make it log a message if successful or unsuccessful.
e.g. "The text is on the page" and "The text is not on the page"
I would like to utilize and if-else statement and system.out to do this.
The following code waits for the text but does not log the result nicely.

```
public static void waitForText(WebDriver driver, String text) throws Exception {
    final String searchText = text;
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getPageSource().contains(searchText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: User2406649. Thanks for your response but I would like to have a system.out message logged stating whether it was successful or unsuccessful. Not just if unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like Logger (Simple Java Logger or Apache Log4j will work) with try and catch.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class);
try{
  //Do Something
  logger.info("Message");
}
catch(Exception e){
  logger.error("Message " + e);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: On addition - you need to catch NoSuchElementException